# How to chain message sinks in a context bound object (aspect oriented programming)

Tags: c#, .net, aop

I am trying to use `ContextBoundObject` and message sinks to inject some aspects into my code.

My problem is that my aspect is being called only once - 
    when I make the call: `myFacadee.GetValue("Tie")`
    I would expect to see my caching aspect be called twice

1. Once for the '`GetValue`' method
2. Secondly for the '`GetValues`' which is called internally in the
   '`GetValue`' method

However, it's being called only once for the first '`GetValue`' method call.

*How can change/fix the following code to make sure that all the methods on my '`MyFacade`' object cause the caching aspect to be invoked. Even if they are being called by other methods in the same '`MyFacde`' object?*

Here is a simplified example of what my code looks like:

**Test Application:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myFacadee = new MyFacade();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Value:\t" + myFacadee.GetValue("Tie"));

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Facade:**

```
[Cache]
public class MyFacade : ContextBoundObject
{
    public string GetValue(string name)
    {
        return GetValues().FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith(name));
    }

    public List<string> GetValues()
    {
        return new List<string>
                   {
                       "You asked for a Shirt",
                       "You asked for a Pants",
                       "You asked for a Tie"
                   };
    }
}
```

**CacheAttribute:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CacheAttribute : ContextAttribute
{
    public CacheAttribute() : base("Security") { }

    public override void GetPropertiesForNewContext(IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
    {
        ctorMsg.ContextProperties.Add(new CacheProperty());
    }
}
```

**CacheProperty:**

```
public class CacheProperty : IContextProperty, IContributeObjectSink
{
    public IMessageSink GetObjectSink(MarshalByRefObject o, IMessageSink next)
    {
        return new CacheAspect(next);
    }

    public void Freeze(Context newContext)
    {
        // no op
    }

    public bool IsNewContextOK(Context ctx)
    {
        var newContextLogProperty = ctx.GetProperty("CacheProperty") as CacheProperty;
        if (newContextLogProperty == null)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false);
            return false;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    public string Name { get { return "CacheProperty"; } }
}
```

**CacheAspect:**

```
internal class CacheAspect : IMessageSink
{
    internal CacheAspect(IMessageSink next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    private readonly IMessageSink _next;

    public IMessageSink NextSink
    {
        get { return _next; }
    }

    public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        Preprocess(msg);

        var returnMethod = _next.SyncProcessMessage(msg);

        return returnMethod;
    }

    public IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private void Preprocess(IMessage msg)
    {
        // We only want to process method calls
        if (!(msg is IMethodMessage)) return;

        var call = msg as IMethodMessage;
        var type = Type.GetType(call.TypeName);
        var callStr = type.Name + "." + call.MethodName;

        var argsString = call.Args.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);

        Console.WriteLine("Try to get value form cache : {0} for {1}({2})", callStr, call.MethodName, argsString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only getting called once because the context boundry is only crossed once. A call to the same instance from within the instance does not require any marshalling into the context, hence your sink is not used to intercept a message.

Comment: thank you! sometimes the correct answer is: you are trying to do something that will not work so maybe it's best to consider a different approach

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this; I will try changing target to AttributeTargets.Method.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CacheAttribute : ContextAttribute
```

Comment: that's not going to work because ContextAttribute is decorated with [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `AttributeUsage` to be targeting only the Methods and also make the "`[Cache]`" in the method itself you need, in your case it should be "`GetValues`" not "`GetValue`" which will cause all items to be cached in a collection and later you could read from that cache.

One of the leading AOP components which have reputation is [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com)